# Regular expression for a range of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

im trying to do a regex but cant understand so well.

What i want is to input the following:

```
09XYZZZZZZ
```

Where X is from 6 to 9, Y 1 to 9, and Z 0 to 9. All together, only 12 digits length.

Thanks !

Comment: Please post something that you've tried before asking for help.

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ <-- this tool will help you understand regex a log better.

Comment: You say 12 in length, but your sample only has 10. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution depends heavily on the type of regex used. In Perl regex, for example, you can write:

```
/09[6-9][1-9][0-9]{6}/
```

This matches exactly the string 09, then exactly one digit from 6 to 9, then exactly one digit from 1 to 9, and lastly exactly 6 digits from 0 to 9.

In POSIX regex, the `{6}` notation does not exist. You will have to repeat the range 6 times there.

Please note that your example pattern is only 10 digits long, while your description says 12 digits. If you want a maximum of 12 digits, and an arbitrary number of Z at the end, you can use

```
/09[6-9][1-9][0-9]+/
```

in Perl or

```
/09[6-9][1-9][0-9][0-9]*/
```

in POSIX - the `+` notation does not exist there.

Comment: Ranges do exist in POSIX regexp (both BRE and ERE, though the much more common BRE need backslashes for them); `+` exists in ERE but can be emulated with `\{1,\}` in BRE. The rest is of course correct.

Answer (score 1):

`09[6-9][1-9][0-9]{8}`

[Explain regex](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=09%5B6-9%5D%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B8%7D)

Answer (score 1):

```
/^09[6-9][1-9][3-9]{6}.{2}$/
```

That should do what you want, assuming the last 2 digits can be anything since you didn't specify them.

Breaking it down:

`^` matches the start of the string

`09` matches `"09"` exactly

`[6-9]` and similar define ranges for a character

`[3-9]{6}` says we want 6 occurrences between 3 and 9

`.{2}` means 2 of anything.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, POSIX does have ranges, see [re_format(7)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man7/re_format).

Common are POSIX BASIC REGULAR EXPRESSIONS:

```
09[6-9][1-9][0-9]\{6\}
```

Adjust the 6 to 8 if the twelve digits are correct. You can write this for a more flexible range of numbers:

```
09[6-9][1-9][0-9]\{6,8\}
```

Sometimes, you have POSIX ERE though:

```
09[6-9][1-9][0-9]{6}
```

POSIX ERE support + like PCRE, BRE don’t but you can use `\{6,\}` for open end there. POSIX regex do not, like PCRE (see Dominik’s answer for them), need delimiters as part of the regular expression.

See [perlre(1)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/perlre) and [perlretut(1)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/perlretut) for Perl regular expressions, to which PCRE is *mostly* compatible.

PHP uses PCRE these days, in case you wonder.